# How to Copy a complete XML-file in laravel from public to storage folder

Tags: xml, laravel, controller, file-copying

In my Laravel project I would like to copy a .xml file named config.xml from the public/xml folder to the storage/Admin/webapp folder.(The storage is symlinked) It seems like I can´t get it to work. I always get a "Cannot create Root directory" exception.

If i dd the variables i get the results i want to see. I tried several ways to get it right by changing / to \ or deleting and adding some / or using several Commands from laravel like asset etc. It seems like i can get the .xml file and even dispaly its content with dd but i get exceptions copying it afterwards? There is a double Root. Two times C:\ but i dont know where its comming from.

I would expect a copy of the config.xml file from the public folder in my storage folder as config.xml file

```
public function copyXml()
  {
    //Create Filepath and get XML File
    $content = file_get_contents(public_path('/xml/config.xml'));

    //Set destination path
    $destination = storage_path('/Admin/webapp');

    //Copy xml-file
    Storage::put($content, $destination);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

---

[image]

By default local disk looks into project_root_folder/storage/app/. You can't access and manipulate files in public folder through Storage facade.

```
//Get file content from public path
$content = file_get_contents(public_path('xml/config.xml'));

//Set destination path
$destination = storage_path('admin/webapp/config.xml');

//Put content in the destination path
Storage::put($destination, $content);
```